# How can I have inner join and a case expresion in a DB2 update statement?

Tags: sql-server, db2

I have the following MSSQL update statement that contains innner join and a case expression in the update statement is it possible convert the update statement into DB2 update state.

```
UPDATE LIBNAME1.OPTR_POS_FIX
SET VAL_TYPE = @VAL_TYPE
,PORT_SNAME = @PORT_SNAME
,ISIN_NO = @ISIN_NO
,SEC_SNAME = @SEC_SNAME
,SEC_CCY_ABBR = @SEC_CCY_ABBR
,BASE_CCY = @BASE_CCY
,TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE = @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE
,QUANTITY = @QUANTITY
,MKT_PRICE = @MKT_PRICE
,AVG_COST = @AVG_COST
,MVAL_AMT_SC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (
        CASE 
            WHEN FDBVAL.VLGTI = 100
                THEN 100
            ELSE 1
            END
        ), 3)
,MVAL_AMT_BC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (
        CASE 
            WHEN FDBVAL.VLGTI = 100
                THEN 100
            ELSE 1
            END
        ) / @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE, 3)
,AVG_BVAL_SC = @AVG_BVAL_SC
,AVG_BVAL_BC = @AVG_BVAL_BC
,INT_AMT_SC = @INT_AMT_SC
,INT_AMT_BC = @INT_AMT_BC
FROM LIBNAME1.OPTR_POS_FIX
INNER JOIN LIBNAME2.FDBVAL ON OPTR_POS_FIX.SEC_CODE = FDBVAL.VLVALR
WHERE (OPTR_POS_FIX.VALN_DATE = @VALN_DATE)
AND (OPTR_POS_FIX.PORT_CODE = @PORT_CODE)
AND (OPTR_POS_FIX.SEC_CODE = @SEC_CODE)
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to add some sample how your table looks like. That should help you to find answers. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would write the `UPDATE` statement in Db2

```
UPDATE LIBNAME1.OPTR_POS_FIX F
SET VAL_TYPE      = @VAL_TYPE
,PORT_SNAME       = @PORT_SNAME
,ISIN_NO          = @ISIN_NO
,SEC_SNAME        = @SEC_SNAME
,SEC_CCY_ABBR     = @SEC_CCY_ABBR
,BASE_CCY         = @BASE_CCY
,TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE = @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE
,QUANTITY         = @QUANTITY
,MKT_PRICE        = @MKT_PRICE
,AVG_COST         = @AVG_COST
,AVG_BVAL_SC      = @AVG_BVAL_SC
,AVG_BVAL_BC      = @AVG_BVAL_BC
,INT_AMT_SC       = @INT_AMT_SC
,INT_AMT_BC       = @INT_AMT_BC
,(MVAL_AMT_SC, MVAL_AMT_BC)
 = (SELECT ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (CASE WHEN F.VLGTI = 100 THEN 100 ELSE 1 END ), 3) 
    ,      ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (CASE WHEN F.VLGTI = 100 THEN 100 ELSE 1 END ) / @TRX_BCCY_EX_RATE, 3)
    FROM  LIBNAME2.FDBVAL V
    WHERE  F.SEC_CODE = V.VLVALR
    )
WHERE 
    VALN_DATE  = @VALN_DATE
AND PORT_CODE  = @PORT_CODE
AND SEC_CODE   = @SEC_CODE
AND EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM  LIBNAME2.FDBVAL V
    WHERE  F.SEC_CODE = V.VLVALR
)
```

Comment: Thanks, the statement looks fine, but it does not recognize the OPTR_POS_FIX table name in the first where expression. "OPTR_POS_FIX.SEC_CODE = FDBVAL.VLVALR"

Comment: I’ve edited the answer to use aliases. It should fix it. Although I think you are not using any columns from the joined table so you actually only need the EXISTS

Comment: I found out that the driver does not like the parameters. I get the following error message: I get the the following error message: Error Source: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries Error Message: Not enough parameters specified. The commaned requires 22 parameter(s) but only 0 parameter(s). exist in the parameter collection

Comment: Sounds like you now need to pass the parameters. If you are stuck on know how to do that in your iSeries environment, ask another SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this assuming, that *@var* are some application parameters:

```
MERGE INTO LIBNAME1.OPTR_POS_FIX O
USING LIBNAME2.FDBVAL F ON O.SEC_CODE = F.VLVALR
AND (O.VALN_DATE = @VALN_DATE)
AND (O.PORT_CODE = @PORT_CODE)
AND (O.SEC_CODE = @SEC_CODE)

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
  VAL_TYPE = @VAL_TYPE
, ...
, MVAL_AMT_SC = ROUND(@QUANTITY * @MKT_PRICE / (
        CASE 
            WHEN F.VLGTI = 100
                THEN 100
            ELSE 1
            END
        ), 3)
, ...
;
```

Comment: Will give it a try.

Comment: I get the the following error message: Error Source: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries 
Error Message: Not enough parameters specified. The commaned requires 22 parameter(s) but only 0 parameter(s). 
exist in the parameter collection.

Comment: It seems that the driver does not like the parameters.

Comment: Parameter marker use depends on an application interface you use. '?' sign should work everywhere.

Comment: "?" unamed parameter is not flexible for what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks the update statement works. I used the code page to manually pass the named parameters